Query for Merging Repeated Values

How can I get the result like attached picture
Here is my SQL Server Script:
-- Create table
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50)
);

-- Insert records
INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe');

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (2, 'Jane', 'Smith');

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (3, 'Hamza', 'Johnson');

INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (4, 'Hamza', 'Tes');


The visualization is typically something you would handle in the presentation layer (e.g. PHP, JS, etc.).

This is a presentation issue, not a SQL issue. Datasets aren't Excel worksheets, there's no such feature as "merged cells".

I suggest, instead, that you work out what product you are going to use to display your data, and then ask about that application (though note that may not be on-topic for [so], so make sure you ask on the right site). Don't forget to demonstrate your attempt(s) and explain why they didn't work, and/or detail what you didn't understand about the research you've performed to achieve the goal.

SqlServer doesn't support merged (or colored) cells in current versions, so unfortunately you can't. Btw, shouldn't "Johnson" also be merged in similar way?

How can I get the result like attached picture Copy the result in excell, and merge both cells. It's not possible in sql, sql only provides data it does not care how it is presented

SQL doesn't support merging cells like Excel as you share in image, but you can group by FirstName and concatenate LastName values with a comma, as shown in the example, This might help achieve a similar result.
SELECT 
    MIN(EmployeeID) AS EmployeeID, 
    FirstName,
    STRING_AGG(LastName, ', ') AS LastName
FROM 
    Employee
GROUP BY 
    FirstName
ORDER BY 
   EmployeeID

https://dbfiddle.uk/EF7pEwFr
